# basic node - "require is not defined" for simple hello world

Tags: javascript, node.js

Connecting the dots question here. I've been working locally through nodeschool.io tutorials and am ready to make the big leap into writing my first app with node. Aaaaand, already hit a basic stumbling block which isn't cleared up in the docs.

A hello world app on at osx localhost:8080 using http-server fails as soon as the script loads and calls node's core require.

What am I missing about how node runs that makes me think I can load nodejs core functionality on a server with nodejs running globally?

**index.html**

```
<script src="load.js"></script>
```

**load.js**

```
var hello = require('hello');
console.log(hello);
```

**hello.js**

```
module.exports = "Hello World";
```

**Error:** Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Thank you!

Comment: `require` is part of commonjs, requirejs or other libraries. they can run in the browser.

Comment: you should run load with `node load.js`

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run that in a browser environment. If not, what is `index.html` all about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this js in the browser then you can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/). This will let you use some features of node like require.

You would need to run your js code through browserify prior to linking it in your html.

For example once your code is ready run

```
browserify main.js -o load.js
```

Then in your html

```
<script src="load.js"></script>
```